# Potentiometer is not responding as expected on an esp32 through webserver. Http requests and micropython

Tags: html, sockets, esp32, webapi, micropython

I am using the following code to access a webserver, and control the elements of my board (Led's, neopixel, temperature sensor, button and potentiometer). I can turn on led, change color of neopixel and read state of button and the temperature. The problem arises when i try to access the potentiometer. Attached is a picture of the webserver menu, and by clicking the potentiometer link i get an error screen of "This page isnt working, 192.168.4.1 didnt send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE. Rather than the error screen I am trying to get it to print the potentiometer value below all the menu choices like it does with all the other elements of the board. I cant see where im going wrong, it seems the code is linking to the correct page, and the problem is with the potentiometer. I have created another file with using the same Pin and potentiometer, and it seems it is reading the values fine with just potentiometer.read(). Hope someone can point me in the correct direction. Thank you!

[image: Menu of webserver]

```
`import network
import socket
import time
import machine
from machine import Pin, SoftI2C, ADC
from neopixel import NeoPixel

intled = machine.Pin(32, machine.Pin.OUT)

button = Pin(12, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_DOWN)
mcp = SoftI2C(scl=Pin(22), sda=Pin(23))
 
potentiometer = ADC(Pin(27))
potentiometer.atten(ADC.ATTN_11DB)
#potentiometer.atten(ADC.ATTN_0DB)
neoled = NeoPixel(Pin(21), 2)

address = 24
temp_reg = 5 
res_reg = 8
def temperature(data): 
    value = data[0] << 8 | data[1]
    temp = (value & 0xFFF) / 16.0
    if value & 0x1000:
        temp -= 256.0
    return temp

ssid = "m"
password = "p"
 
wlan = network.WLAN(network.AP_IF)
wlan.active(True)
wlan.config(essid=ssid, password=password)

html = """<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head> <title>Group11</title> </head>
        <body> <h1>Group11</h1>
            <p>Assignment 41111</p>
            <p>
            <a href='/light/on'>Turn Light On</a>
            </p>
            <p>
            <a href='/light/off'>Turn Light Off</a>
            </p>
            <p>
            <a href='/button'>Button Value</a>
            </p>
            <p>
            <a href='/temperature'>Read Temperature</a>
            </p>
            <p>
            <a href='/potentiometer'>Read potentiometer</a>
            </p>
            <p>
            <a href='/neopixel/red'>Neopixel Red</a>
            </p>
            <p>
            <a href='/neopixel/green'>Neopixel Green</a>
            </p>
            <p>
            <a href='/neopixel/yellow'>Neopixel Yellow</a>
            </p>
            <p>
            <a href='/neopixel/off'>Neopixel Off</a>
            </p>
            <br>
        </body>
    </html>
"""
 
# Open socket
addr = socket.getaddrinfo('0.0.0.0', 80)[0][-1]
 
s = socket.socket()
s.bind(addr)
s.listen(1)
 
print('listening on', addr)
print('AP IP address:', wlan.ifconfig()[0])

stateis = ""
 

while True:
    try:
        cl, addr = s.accept()
        print('client connected from', addr)

        request = cl.recv(1024)
        print(request)

        request = str(request)
        led_on = request.find('/light/on')
        led_off = request.find('/light/off')
        check_button = request.find('/button')
        temperature = request.find('/temperature')
        potentiometervalue = request.find('/potentiometer')
        neopixelred = request.find('/neopixel/red')
        neopixelgreen = request.find('/neopixel/green')
        neopixelyellow = request.find('/neopixel/yellow')
        neopixeloff = request.find('/neopixel/off')
        
        print( 'led on = ' + str(led_on))
        print( 'led off = ' + str(led_off))
        print( 'button_state = ' + str(button.value()))
        print( 'temperature = ' + str(temperature))
        #print( 'potentiometervalue = ' + str(potentiometer.read()))
        print( 'neopixel red = ' + str(neopixelred))
        print( 'neopixel green = ' + str(neopixelgreen))
        print( 'neopixel yellow = ' + str(neopixelyellow))
        print( 'neopixel off = ' + str(neopixeloff))

        if led_on == 6:
            print("led on")
            intled.value(1)
            stateis = "LED is ON"

        if led_off == 6:
            print("led off")
            intled.value(0)
            stateis = "LED is OFF"
            
        if check_button == 6:
            print(button.value())
            strbutton=str(button.value())
            
            stateis = strbutton
            
        if temperature == 6:
            address = 24
            temp_reg = 5 
            res_reg = 8
            def temperature(data): 
                value = data[0] << 8 | data[1]
                temp = (value & 0xFFF) / 16.0
                if value & 0x1000:
                    temp -= 256.0
                return temp
            print("temperature")
            data = bytearray(2) 
            mcp.readfrom_mem_into(address, temp_reg, data)
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print(temperature(data))
            tempa = str(temperature(data))
            time.sleep(0.5)
            stateis = tempa
            
        if potentiometervalue == 6:
            
            print(potentiometer.read())
            time.sleep(1)
            stateis = str(potentiometer.read())
        
        if neopixelred == 6:
            neoled[0] = (0, 20, 0)
            neoled[1] = (0, 20, 0)
            neoled.write()
            print("Neopixel Red")
            stateis = "Neopixel is Red"
        
        if neopixelgreen == 6:
            neoled[0] = (20, 0, 0)
            neoled[1] = (20, 0, 0)
            neoled.write()
            print("Neopixel Green")
            stateis = "Neopixel is Green"
            
        if neopixelyellow == 6:
            neoled[0] = (20, 20, 0)
            neoled[1] = (20, 20, 0)
            neoled.write()
            print("Neopixel Yellow")
            stateis = "Neopixel is Yellow"
            
        if neopixeloff == 6:
            neoled[0] = (0, 0, 0)
            neoled[1] = (0, 0, 0)
            neoled.write()
            print("Neopixel off")
            stateis = "Neopixel is Off"
        
        
        
        
        response = html + stateis
        
        cl.send('HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-type: text/html\r\n\r\n')
        cl.send(response)
        cl.close()
 
    except OSError as e:
        cl.close()
        print('connection closed')`
```

I have some sections commented out. Mainly, if i uncomment '#print( 'potentiometervalue = ' + str(potentiometer.read()))' then i cant get a connection to the webserver at all. So i have left this one commented out for now. I have tried changing ADC.ATTN around, to no avail. As mentioned i have also tried the potentiometer on said Pin in another code just running only on the board, and it works as expected.

Comment: You're going to have a hard time debugging this if you only look at whether the web server responds or not. Hook the board to your computer, open its serial port and see what it's saying.